# Is there a way to attach a handler to applyStyle() in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a style loaded in via the [CKEditor styleSet](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_styles) that, depending on where it is being placed contextually, I'd like to perform additional content manipulation. Specifically, when the style is applied within a bulleted or numbered list, I'd like to move a level up the elementPath and perform special handling on the parent `<li>`.

I haven't been able to identify an event that I can bind to which would fire after `applyStyle()`. Is there one?

There are probably other solutions to this problem, is there a different and/or optimal way of handling this scenario in CKEditor?

One thing I've looked at a little bit is a Style customHandler, but I'm not sure how I would override the `apply()` and `remove()` functions but still call into the default functionality in the prototype.

**Note:** If the [CSS :has pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) was supported I wouldn't be trying to do this at all.